# Chrome / Firefox inspect show the same font but actually not

Tags: css

I have two helps text in the same page.
However, they just look like different with the same font-family.

Updated:

The font 2 displays not like `Lato` at all and the `font 2` is inside a iframe. There's no error on the developer console.

## Font 1

[image: inline]
[image: inline]

## Font 2

[image: inline]

[image: inline]

Comment: The font is not getting loaded. What you are seeing is default font of browser. Are you getting any error in console?

Comment: Could you share the code to see the issue?

Comment: The code more than 100 files? it's hard to share with that. so sorry

Comment: You are required to post a minimal example of the code you are using that we can use to reproduce the problem. [mcve] If you think you cannot do that, then Stack Overflow is not the place to ask this question, because anything said is only a wild guess.

Answer (score 3):

This issue mainly arises when you do not add all format of font file.. so include all format like ttf, otf, svg etc.

Steps you have to follow

1) Download ttf file for which you want to apply font in your project.

2) Generate CSS for those fonts.You can use below online tool or similar to generate CSS and other formats.

https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

3) Then include that CSS in your project, and also set path accordingly.
If you still face problem let me know I am always available to help

Thanks !!

Comment: it help me a lot. :)